# Load CSS Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to load in my css for a WordPress theme however it doesn't seem to load.

Here is what I have so far

[image: file structure]

[image: styling]

[image: WP error]

I am new to building WordPress themes so any help is great.

Comment: you need to have a `style.css` file in the parent directory, your style is in a sub-folder

Comment: **Do not post pictures of your code**, include the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Your main style.css file needs to be in the root folder. Move style.css from the css folder to the root folder (same folder as index.php).

Answer (score 0):

> > Custom Theme need two files

i)style.css
ii)functions.php

> > you can call your style sheet from functions.php using hooks
> >     ex:

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri().'yourstylesheetname.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some **Required Theme Files** that you have to add in your theme folder in order to start

You have at least to have these two files: `style.css` & `index.php`

I see that you have an `index.php` thats's good, but for the `style.css` file in `yourThemeFolder/css` folder, hasn't been recognized by wordpress, because In order for WordPress to recognize the set of theme template files as a valid theme, the `style.css` file needs to be located in the root directory of your theme, not a subdirectory, (the same directory of you `index.php` file).

Take a look at [Required Theme Files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/release/required-theme-files/) or [Main Stylesheet CSS](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/) for more Information.